# Filter in react bootstrap table

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am new in reactjs and I am trying to filter in the react-bootstrap table next and it should show all records in the table if search text is empty but now there is nothing show even search text box is empty.

I was looking for one text search box for all column filter design in the react-bootstrap table next and I found this example

[Example link](https://codepen.io/tannerlinsley/pen/MoQome?editors=0010)

So I apply this idea to my code

Here is my filter method=>

```
filterData(event) {
  this.setState({
    timesheetstemp: this.state.timesheets,
    searchvalue: event.target.value
  });

  let data = this.state.timesheetstemp;

  console.log(event.target.value);

  if (this.state.searchfield && this.state.searchvalue) {
    if (this.state.searchfield === 'Emp ID') {
      data = data.filter(row => {
        row.empid.includes(this.state.searchvalue)
      })
    } else if (this.state.searchfield === 'Shift') {
      data = data.filter(row => {
        row.empid.includes(this.state.searchvalue)
      })
    } else if (this.state.searchfield === 'Cost Center') {
      data = data.filter(row => {
        row.empid.includes(this.state.searchvalue)
      })
    } else {
      data = data.filter(row => {
        row.empid.includes(this.state.searchvalue) || row.shiftid.includes(this.state.searchvalue) || row.shiftid.includes(this.state.searchvalue)
      })
    }
  }

  this.setState({
    timesheetstemp: data
  })
}
```

Here is my Table =>

```
 <BootstrapTable keyField={"id"} data={this.state.timesheetstemp} columns={columns}>


                  </BootstrapTable>
```

Here is my search textbox =>

```
 <Form.Control type="text" className="form-control width-300px float-md-right form-control-sm ml-3" placeholder="Search" value={this.state.searchvalue} onChange={this.filterData}/>
```

But why after clear text box is not shown all data in the table?

Comment: just use the setState and its fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous, so if you want to access the new state after you set it, you should use `setState`'s callback function:

```
 this.setState({
    timesheetstemp: this.state.timesheets,
    searchvalue: event.target.value
  }, () => {

  let data = this.state.timesheetstemp;

  console.log(event.target.value);

  if (this.state.searchfield && this.state.searchvalue) {
  //...
  })
```